# User input from batch file is not resolving in command

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Long story short, I need to map a series of WebDav folders that for whatever reason, at different times, require repeated attempts to authenticate in order to do so successfully.

I have created the following script to make things easier, namely so I don't have to copy and paste the net use command for the first share 15 times and then hope that by the 15th time, it was able to connect successfully.

What I am trying to do is attempt a "regular" map the first time. If that doesn't work (which we will know because it will check if a folder in that location "exists", which it should if the drive mapped successfully) then it will prompt again for credentials, just in case I mistyped the password (although this is rare). Ideally, I would like to be able to *** out the password when it is typed, as right now it appears as plain text.

Then, using the password, which I stored in the variable "pword", I have a loop that attempts to map the location over and over again using the password stored in the variable until it can successfully connect.

**I realize I could just put the password in the script**. This is in a public location, so I really didn't even want the username in the script to begin with. I can't put the password in the script. Right now, it prompts for the password for the account since one is not provided. Password goes after username and before the /P:no switch, which ensures the drive does not *persist* after the session.

Currently, this is not working (no surprise). I can't figure out why though. My script is looping, but I keep getting `System error 1244 has occurred. The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated.` So somehow, the password I manually submit to the variable interactively is not getting passed into the net use switch as it should. I get error 1244 whether I enter the correct password at the prompt or not, so somehow it isn't attempting to connect with the credentials supplied manually through the variable.

How can I fix this so user input is *** (starred) out (since it's prompting for a password, though cmd.exe doesn't know that) and more importantly, I can brute force the connection by entering my password ONCE (well, twice) and then having my batch file automatically sub that in for the password instead of prompting EVERY single time. That gets annoying, doing that 15 times every time I log on. Is there something wrong here, or a better way to do this?

```
net use k: "https://d.docs.live.net/###/Documents/somefolder" /USER:someuser@outlook.com /P:No
if exist "K:\x" GOTO ContinueMapping
echo Windows will try to connect using the following password:
set /p pword=WebDav password:
:BruteConnect
net use k: "https://d.docs.live.net/$$$/Documents/somefolder" /USER:signin.interlinked@outlook.com %pword% /P:No
if exist "K:\x" GOTO ContinueMapping
GOTO BruteConnect
:ContinueMapping
(More drives get mapped here, and they all map successfully once the first drive gets mapped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is not actually creating the network connection.

There is a gap in time before the connection becomes active. The credentials are stored in your credential manager, but the connection to this kind of location becomes active once you query access to it.

The Access Denied: 5 error comes from the fact that you are not running your script as Administrator, and that is required to perform a Net Use command.

It would be the exact same to enter that address in your explorer window, press enter, wait 10 to 20 seconds before the connection is established, and then the K drive will also spontaneously work.

If you were to prompt for a password, your script would still fail unless you run it as administrator, but then the first version of your script would already work.

Do note, that when you use this method, the script will stall for 10-20 seconds when it attempts to create the connection before it succeeds.

So in theory, you could simply just call the script normally as you already do, wait 10 to 20 seconds and it will magically start to work.

This is a known problem with accessing shares such as those by Office365/Sharepoint/etc. Microsoft substituted that for OneDrive because of how often it has connection problems like these.